# UITextView Font size class not change

Tags: ios, uitextview, size-classes

I try to set font size class of UITextView in storyboard, but it always shows system font (default font, size and color). It shows the correct font if I don't set font size class.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

It is matter of 'selectable' property of `UITextView`.

Check the *selectable* property of `UITextView` in Storyboard Editor to set it YES.

and later in `viewWillAppear` set this property to `NO`.

```
textview.text = @"some text";
textview.selectable = NO;
```

Comment: Do you know why this happens?

Comment: No idea..but doing above fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     _linkTextView.editable = YES;
     _linkTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f];
     _linkTextView.editable = NO;
}
```

Instead of system font you can use your font.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question. It seems like an attempt at a coded workaround, without explaining why it didn't work when the user tried setting it in Interface Builder. Also, you're setting it to a static system font, when we can infer from the question that the user is trying to achieve a font other than the system font.

Answer (score -1):

You can use .attributedText on your TextView and set an AttributedString there, so you can easily customise your TextView.

```
NSString *yourString = "your text";
NSMutableAttributedString *ms = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];
[ms addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40] range:NSMakeRange(0, yourString.length)];
```